# Xcode: Different behavior between swift Int and Objective-C int

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, xcode11.4

I'm trying to convert `Swift` function to `Objective-C`. This is the signature of the functions

Swift:

```
func hammingWeight(_ n: Int) -> Int
```

Objective-C

```
-(int) hammingWeight:(int) number
```

I'm passing this value to function/method:

```
00000000000000000000000000001011
```

In the case of Swift if I print the value of n it prints this:

```
p n
(Int) $R2 = 1011
```

In the case of Objective-C prints this:

```
p number
(int) $0 = 521
```

My question to you guys is why Objective-C is changing the value of I'm passing. It makes no sense to me. Any of you knows why this is happening or if there is a way around this?

I'll really appreciate your help with this.

This is the complete Objective-C implementation:

```
@interface DoSomething : NSObject
@end

@implementation DoSomething

-(int) hammingWeight:(int) number {
    NSLog(@"number %d", number);
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        DoSomething *doIt = [DoSomething new];
        [doIt hammingWeight:00000000000000000000000000001011];
    }
}
```

Comment: 1011 in oct  is 521 dec so make sure you are not passing it as oct number to the objc function.

Comment: @HossamSherif I have add it the complete objective-c implementation

Comment: Yes you are sending it as oct .. try sending 0xB as Hex which is `1011` as Binary or send `11` as decimal. and if you want to send it as oct the `1011` binary is `013` oct

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that in (Objective-)c your given number is interpreted as octal due to the prefixed `0`, while in Swift, it is interpreted as decimal.

For octal Int literals in Swift prefix `0o`.

Information on octal Int literals in the [Swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#grammar_octal-literal)
Information on octal int numbers in [c documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Constants)

```
// Swift:
(lldb) po 0o0000000000000000000000000001011;
521

(lldb) po 00000000000000000000000000001011;
1011

// Objective-C
(lldb) po 1011
1011

(lldb) po 01011
521
```